# Зачем нужно писать в метод класс rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Зачем нужно писать rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D()? Если мы и так взаимодействуем им, когда написали Rigidbody2D rb; Что означает rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D()?
Извините если не понятно написал

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Flip();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для наглядности это можно записать так:

```
[Тип переменной] [Имя переменной] = [Значение переменной];
```

Например когда мы пишем:

```
float speed = 100f;
```

Мы объявляем переменную типа *float* с именем *speed* и присваиваем ей значении *100f*.

Если мы объявляем переменную и не присваиваем ей никакого значения, то компилятор сделает это за нас и присвоит значение по умолчанию. Для *float* это будет **0f**. Для *Rigidbody2D* это будет **null** (отсутствие ссылки, пустота).

Естественно с пустотой работать не получится и строчкой кода:

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

мы присваиваем переменной *rb* типа *Rigidbody2D* значение конкретного **Rigidbody2D**.

Компилятор не может сам догадаться о каком именно *Rigidbody2D* идет речь, потому что мы можем хотеть работать с компонентом *Rigidbody2D*, подключенном к другому игровому объекту (или даже создать новый *Rigidbody2D*). Например, мы могли использовать такую строчку кода, что бы подключить к переменной *rb* компонент *Rigidbody2D* с игрового объекта с тегом *Enemy*:

```
rb = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

*PS: этот мой первый ответ на этом сайте, дайте знать если я сделал что-то не так.*

Answer (score 0):

```
// обьявление ПУСТОЙ переменной типа Rigidbody2D
Rigidbody2D rb; 

void Start()
{
    // Инициализация даной переменной при создании инстанса Player в сцене
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
}
```

если строки инициализации не будет, то `rb` будет `null`.
Соответственно, ты получишь `null reference exception` как только попробуешь что-либо сделать с ним.

---

и отдельно стоит отметить что здесь ПРАВИЛЬНО размещен этот запрос - на старте. Плохая практика это писать в других местах кроме Start  или  Awake