# Объект вращается при движение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Двигаю объект по сцене с помощью

`moveVector.x = moveContr.Horizontal() * speed;`

`moveContr` это другой скрипт, вот метод :

```
public float Horizontal()

    {
        if (inputVector.x != 0)
            return inputVector.x;
        else
            return Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    }
```

игра под андроид, и получается что когда я двигаю виртуал джойстик, то моделька персонажа просто крутится по одной оси (это происходит лишь при движении), что на кнопках, что на джойстике, одно и тоже.
Я думал проблема в джойстике, но нет, не пойму до сих пор откуда здесь это долбанное вращение, подскажет кто чего? в чем проблема то?
если нужна еще какая-то часть кода конкретная, могу приложить в комментариях уже

Comment: А moveVector это устаревший встроенный тип или что-то ваше?
И если второе, то что с ним происходит потом?

Comment: дальше, это в плане? 
кстати вот что это такое:
private Vector3 moveVector;

Comment: Что бы понять что это такое можно прочитать вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176832/406362 . 
По поводу того, что дальше. Вот вы поменяли значение moveVector.x , - что вы дальше с moveVector делаете?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в Rigidbody -> Constraints -> Freeze Rotation поставить галочку.

Comment: мне нужен поворот, в этом соль, типо рпг с видом сверху, персонаж по Y  должен вращаться