# Переместить объект в Unity (у меня это квадрат) по оси X на длину стороны этого квадрата?

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d

Как я могу переместить объект в Unity (у меня это квадрат) по оси X на длину стороны этого квадрата? Пробовал писать следующее, но в консоли вижу "width: 0 height: 0"

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Vector2 targetPosition;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    public Vector3 size;
    private MeshRenderer renderer;
    private Bounds bounds;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bounds = renderer.bounds;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        width = bounds.size.x;
        height = bounds.size.y;
        print("width: "+width+" height: "+height);
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
          //  rigid.velocity = Vector2.left * force;
          targetPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x + width, transform.position.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
           // rigid.velocity = Vector2.right * force;
           targetPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x - width, transform.position.y);
        }
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, стоит работать не с вакуумом, а с конкретным компонентом, добавив в метод `start` такую строчку:

`renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();`

Вот ответ объяняющий работу `GetComponent`: [Зачем в методах писать GetComponent?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176769/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-rb-getcomponentrigidbody2d/1176832#1176832)

Comment: Попробовал вот так

Comment: public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Vector2 targetPosition;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    public Vector3 size;
    private MeshRenderer renderer;
    private Bounds bounds;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        bounds = renderer.bounds;
        width = bounds.size.x;
        height = bounds.size.y;
        print("width: "+width+" height: "+height);
    }
}

Comment: Но получаю всё равно 0 в консоли

Answer (score 0):

Ну если нужен именно mesh, то можно так к примеру

1. повесить на объект mesh filter, в поле mesh выбрать квадрат
2. повесить mesh renderer, чтобы все видеть

естественно можно задать свой mesh задав месторасположение всех вершин и прочего вручную
со своими прибамбасами, первые два пункта, это чисто вариант по умолчанию, для теста.
Чтобы была хоть какая-то наглядность.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private new MeshRenderer renderer;
        private float width;

        private void Awake()
        {
            renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            width = renderer.bounds.size.x;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                var position = transform.position;
                var x = position.x;
                var y = position.y;
                var newPosition = new Vector2(x + width, y);

                transform.position = newPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В добавление к своему ответу скажу, что с collider.bounds и rendere.bounds будет аналогичный порядок действий